# Detectar que tipo de dispositivo iOS y android

Tags: javascript

¿Saben si hay una forma de detectar qué dispositivo se está usando?, por ejemplo detectar si es iOS5, iOS6, iOS6s, iOS6s plus, etc. Y en android si es Samsung, Hawei, LG, etc. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 5):

```
/**
 * Determina el sistema operativo del móvil.
 * Esta función retorna 'iOS', 'Android', 'Windows Phone', or 'desconocido'.
 *
 * @returns {String}
 */
function getMobileOperatingSystem() {
  var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;

  // Windows Phone debe ir primero porque su UA tambien contiene "Android"
 if (/windows phone/i.test(userAgent)) {
    return "Windows Phone";
 }

 if (/android/i.test(userAgent)) {
    return "Android";
}

     if (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(userAgent) && !window.MSStream) {
    return "iOS";
}

return "desconocido";
}
```

Detección de iOS de: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9039885/177710

Créditos a : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21741841/detecting-ios-android-operating-system

Answer (score 1):

Si, la mejor forma es utilizando el User Agent proporcionado por los headers del navegador. Solo que debes tener en cuenta que este resultado se puede cambiar mediante "plugins" y pudieras estar mostrando el sitio equivocado. Otra cosa es que la cantidad de valores del User Agent es inmensa: [Lista de posibles resultados del User Agent](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php). Sí, hay muchos que están en deshuso pero es igual algo a tener en cuenta mientras estés diseñando las experiencias entre resultados.

Otras soluciones incluyen además del "navigator.useragent" el "navigator.platform" o librerías javascript que hacen lo mismo... salu2!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo de manera manual, detectando el `user agent` o `platform` o puedes no reinventar la rueda y usar una librería para ser más productivo. Por ejemplo, la librería [isMobile](https://github.com/kaimallea/isMobile).

Por medio de esta librería puedes saber si se trata de un dispositivo Appe (phone, ipod, tablet) o Android (phone y tablet). Por ejemplo para saber si se trata de un **móvil** (cell phone):

```
if (isMobile.apple.phone) {
  // hacer algo
}

if (isMobile.android.phone) {
  // hacer otra cosa
}
```

O si no te interesa que dispositivo sea, solo que sea iOS o Android:

```
if (isMobile.apple.device) {
  // hacer algo
}

if (isMobile.android.device) {
  // hacer otra cosa
}
```

Con esta librería puedes detectar más OS, como dispositivos Windows o Amazon o dispositivos de 7 pulgadas.

---

**Nota:** librería funciona para ambos lados, cliente y servidor. En caso de usarse en Node.js, se le debe pasar a la función `isMobile` la cabecera `user-agent`.