# ¿Cómo detectar si el dispositivo es iPhone con CSS?

Tags: css, css3, ios, iphone

Tengo un sitio web que se ve perfectamente en un ordenador de escritorio y en dispositivos Android, pero parte del CSS (p.e. `background-attachment:fixed` con `background-size:cover`) no es "compatible" con dispositivos iOS (y en particular con iPhone).

He encontrado una alternativa para que al menos no se vea mal en iPhone, y la añado usando *media queries* del siguiente modo:

```
@media all and (max-width:414px) {
    .panel {
        background-attachment:scroll;
    }
}
```

Esos estilos se aplicarán sólo a dispositivos con un ancho máximo de 414px (iPhone 7 plus para abajo)... pero me encuentro que entonces también se van a aplicar a dispositivos Android en los que el código funcionaba correctamente sin necesidad de usar esa alternativa.

¿Hay alguna manera de detectar con CSS si el dispositivo es iOS para añadir esa regla exclusivamente en ese caso?

Comment: Eliminé la referencia a JavaScript, porque vi que había una pregunta sobre ese tema que ya tenía respuestas: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/45985/detectar-que-tipo-de-dispositivo-ios-y-android (que es lo que voy a usar a no ser que haya algo específico en CSS)

Comment: Quizás te interese filtrar sólo a Safari. Recomendado: [browser strangeness](https://browserstrangeness.bitbucket.io/css_hacks.html?#safari).

Comment: El error ocurre en ambos Safari y Chrome para iOS. Pero un enlace interesante de todos modos. Gracias

Comment: Chrome para iOS [en realidad usa *iOS WebKit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome#iOS_version) (*parece Chrome, se ve como Chrome, huele como Chrome, pero es igual a Safari por dentro*), por lo que se comporta en las reglas CSS como si fuera Safari... No obstante, lo dejé como comentario porque no responde directamente a la pregunta, pero es una forma interesante si no se quiere depender exclusivamente de una resolución y dimensión fijas para identificar el dispositivo (que varían en cada nueva versión).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Estos media queries sólo aplican a iPhone.

- **portrait** : significa en modo retrato (vertical)
- **landscape**: significa en modo paisaje (horizontal)

#### iPhone 4 y 4s

```
/* ----------- iPhone 4 and 4S ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) {
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}
```

---

#### iPhone 5, 5s, 5c y 5se

```
/* ----------- iPhone 5, 5S, 5C and 5SE ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) {
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}
```

---

#### iPhone 6, 6s, 7 y 8

```
/* ----------- iPhone 6, 6S, 7 and 8 ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { 

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) { 

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) { 

}
```

---

#### iPhone 6+, 7+ y 8+

```
/* ----------- iPhone 6+, 7+ and 8+ ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) { 

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  and (orientation: portrait) { 

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  and (orientation: landscape) { 

}
```

---

#### iPhone X

```
/* ----------- iPhone X ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 812px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) { 

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 812px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  and (orientation: portrait) { 

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 812px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  and (orientation: landscape) { 

}
```

Fuente: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Puedes ver más dispositivos.